# отправить данные и получить ответ localhost

Tags: javascript, php, post, form

всем привет, хочу разобраться как отправлять данные формы , отправить на сервер и получить ответ, делаю на локальном сервере vs studio.

```
async function sendD() {
  const fetchResp = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5500/mail.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(dataForm),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  });
  respons = await fetchResp;
  console.log(respons);
}
```

`dataForm`, это обьект, форма это формально, обьект я собираю из разных мест по чуть чуть

вот файл `mail.php` скрипта который лежит в той же папке папке

```
<?php // на какие данные рассчитан этот скрипт 
header("Content-Type: application/json");
// разбираем JSON-строку на составляющие встроенной командой 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
// отправляем в ответ строку с подтверждением 
echo "Сервер получил следующие данные: имя — $data";
```

ответ 405 и чет не догоняю как делается правильно эта связка??
если кто знает и разбирается желательно помочь с этим примером и указать где туплю, а то с разных сайтов здоровые примеры и куски кода по отдельности уже насмотрелся))

Answer (score 1):

Код состояния протокола HTTP  405 Method Not Allowed, указывает, что метод запроса известен серверу, но был отключен и не может быть использован.
Попробуйте указать метод явно:
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');`